# how to escape backslash inside of quote with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel migrations to create/manage all of my database scripts and I have a migration for creating a trigger.

Here it is

```
DB::unprepared(
    'create trigger update_points_aft_insert
        after insert on votes
        for each row
        begin
            declare u_id integer;
            if NEW.votable_type = "App\\Comment" then
                set u_id = (select user_id from comments where id = NEW.votable_id);
                update users set points=points+NEW.vote where id = u_id;
            end if;
    end;'
);
```

The problem is when I run `show triggers;` I get:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
         Trigger: update_points_aft_insert
           Event: INSERT
           Table: votes
       Statement: begin
                declare u_id integer;
                if NEW.votable_type = "AppComment" then
                    set u_id = (select user_id from comments where id = NEW.votable_id);
                    update users set points=points+NEW.vote where id = u_id;
                end if;
            end
          Timing: AFTER
         Created: NULL
        sql_mode: NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
         Definer: root@localhost
```

character_set_client: utf8
collation_connection: utf8_unicode_ci
  Database Collation: latin1_swedish_ci

As you can see, what mysql read is `if NEW.votable_type = "AppComment" then` instead of what I want: `if NEW.votable_type = "App\Comment" then` ...
Anyone know how I can tell mysql to read the backslash?

EDIT: what worked was using three backslashes

Comment: did you try triple quotes `if NEW.votable_type = """App\\Comment""" then`

Comment: tried it now, and this is result in mysql: `if NEW.votable_type = ""AppComment"" then`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if NEW.votable_type = "App\\\Comment" then` works. I believe the reason that you need two is because mysql needs one backslash and laravel needs one. As per mysql [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html) `\\` will print `\` . But I guess that what happens is that Laravel escapes the first backslash and mysql escapes the second. So you need 3.

Comment: A short explanation of why the code posted in the question doesn't work and why your solution works could help both the OP and the future readers. You could also add a link to the documentation to support your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

For the backslash to be considered you should double it. Therefore, "App\\\\Comment" should give you "App\Comment"

Comment: OP, why you accepted this answer immediately if you already has `App\\Comment` version in your code from the beginning?

Comment: by saying double it I meant 4 backslash. I have updated my answer. Thanks for the observation.

Comment: I used 3 backslashes to make it work, not 4. Using 2 backslashes didnt work

Comment: I have used 3 and it didn't work. Why did you accepted the answer then?

Comment: When you originally wrote it, i thought you used three. So maybe i misread your answer. but three works.